# iOS: Search Options UI

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am building an iPhone app for a library and I want to give few options to the user to search books by. A user can search a book by title, author, topics, or date of publication.

What I want to know what's the best way to display these search options to the user? In terms of HTML, it would be easy - either use a drop down list or radio buttons. I tried using UIPickerView but honestly, that looks terribly ugly and destroys the aesthetics of the view of my app.

The other option I was thnking was using segmented control, but is it possible to have a vertical segment control in stead of horizontal one? The selection texts can be too long.

Any ideas?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3490358/730701).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a vertical segmented control, you'll have to make it yourself. Create a textured image with dividers. I would export each section as a PNG separately. Then create a picture of each section with the "pressed down" gradient and export each segment as a separate PNG again.

I would then make a new class. If there is a specific number of objects in your segmented control or this is a one time thing, the class may not even be necessary. If not, then in the class constructor pass an array with the titles of the segments in your segmented control. For the first and last objects, use the pictures you made with rounded corners. For the objects in between, use the standard pictures. Then put the titles on top. When a segment is tapped (perhaps use hidden `UIButtons`), you can use a delegate method to tell the main search class which one was tapped, and then the class can replace the normal picture of that segment with the pressed down one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the options.

I ended up creating a simple table to show my choices.

User clicks on "search by", which opens up the table with options and then when you select any option, you return back to main view with the chosen search option.