# How to make custom iOS UISegementedControl Top to Bottom without library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm working on an iOS project that requires the basic `UISegmentedControl` but, instead of having the normal left to right layout it requires a top to bottom layout. I have looked in stack overflow and found some libraries that does this. Is there a method I can achieve this without a library?

Comment: Libraries are also code written by someone. If you want to know how to achieve that than you should examine those libraries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490358/can-i-show-an-uisegmentedcontrol-object-in-vertical

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve `UISegmentedControl` top and bottom layout with below code:

**Swift 4:**

```
segmentControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
```

**Objective-C**

```
self.segmentControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- M_PI / 2.0);
```

[image]

Comment: Similarly, Can I rotate the text horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rotate the texts inside by doing like this

```
for view in yourSegmentedControl.subviews {
     for subview in view.subviews {
          if subview is UILabel{
              subview.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2.0))
           }
     }
}
```